# Unity addressables load specific prefab from cloud

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, addressables

Good day!
I'm using the latest addressables version and want to load resources from cloud. To do this, I put the prefabs in one adressable group and named them by their IDs. I use simple script for instantiate them by name, but all group load by it, and I dont understand how to load specific one and instantiate it. Instantiation work fine, but i dont want to load all group, just specific prefab

Everything works fine, a single object is set in the scene by the ID. But by the loading time I realized that all prefabs from addressables group are loaded at the same time. How can I make it so that only a certain prefab is loaded?

To understand, I have one prefab weighing about 1mb and the whole group weighs 20mb. I want to download only one 1mb of my defined prefab. What I should do? didnt found any solution.
My code:

```
    public void PlacePrefabToScene ()
    {
        Addressables.InstantiateAsync(IDname).Completed += OnAddressableInstantiated;
    }
 
    void OnAddressableInstantiated(AsyncOperationHandle<GameObject> handle)
    {
        if (handle.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
        {
            _instanceReference = handle.Result;
        }
    }
    public void ReleaseCloudPrefab()
    {
        Addressables.Release(_instanceReference);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible without placing this prefab in a separate group. Addressables package is built on top of AssetBundles functionality. So you cannot load an asset without loading the whole bundle containing this asset.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same issue

As a result, I found out that a reference to a certain prefab in a group downloads the whole group, as well as all dependencies of that group. Not really a convenient feature for catalog applications.But you can create multiple groups, for separate downloads

Issue solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).